# when blocking `recv()` or `recvfrom()` returns in the case of tcp

Tags: c, tcp, network-programming

when  blocking style `recv()` or `recvfrom()` are used , as below

```
 while(1){
     recv(sock_fd, buf, n, 0);    // when it returns and continue to execute the next line
     do_something();
     .....
   }
```

if for UDP, `recv()` will return if it gets a UDP packets.

but for TCP, since it is byte stream, it seems there is no rules when `recv()` should return.
can anyone explain this a bit? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For stream sockets, `recv()` will return as soon as there is any data at all available to deliver. It's the same rule as for `read()` (on non-socket file descriptors). That means that you might receive as little as a single byte. When `recv()` (or `recvmsg()` or `recvfrom()` or `read()`) returns, you will get all of the data that happens to be available and which fits in your buffer, so you will actually very likely get more than one byte of data at a time, unless the other end sent only one byte and then waited.

Comment: so this means, usually, for TCP, recv() will get one IP packet? if there are IP fragmentation, then what will happen?

Comment: No, you might get more than one IP packet's worth of data, if additional packets arrive before the kernel has a chance to deliver the data from the first packet to you. As for IP fragmentation, no data from any IP fragments is delivered to any higher layer protocol until the complete IP daiatgram is reassembled, so that's quite a different case.

Comment: @misteryes No it doesn't. There is no such thing as a TCP packet. You might get anything from one byte to the length you supplied, and it can span any number of writes at the other end.